# Calculate hash from huge stream

Tags: ruby, sha

I have to calculate a hash from various streams (StringIO, File, chunked http responses...), and the sources are pretty big (around 100MB - 1GB). For example, I have the following code

```
require 'digest'

sha = Digest::SHA256.new
stream = StringIO.new("test\nfoo\nbar\nhello world")
# this could also be a File.open('my_file.txt')
# or a chunked http response

while content = stream.read(2)
  sha.update content
end

puts sha.to_s
```

This works so far, but I was wondering **how the `sha.update` method works**. Does it store a copy from the overall String in its instance, so that the whole content is hold in memory?

This could lead to some serious memory issues, when loading 1GB of data into RAM (and doing this on multiple processes on the same machine)

Comment: Well, checking this is trivial, no?

Comment: Here's the implementation, by the way: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/digest/sha2/sha2.c#L529

Comment: How would you test that? From the implementation I would say, it frees the space (last line `usedspace = freespace = 0;`), am I right?

Comment: "how would you test that?" - umm, give a 1-2 gb file and watch the memory usage? Yes, this thing does not store processed content, it doesn't need to.

Comment: The usage of a hash is to "collect" the input stream which could be "infinite" in length an produce an finite response in the form of a "hash sum". So the sha don't need to hold all the data within the memory